# How to access generated html using Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm using

```
$var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Which gives me access to the HTML code, but almost all the text comes from javascript.

I want to edit a website that uses javascript to serve HTML, is it possible to access the final generated HTML code?

Comment: 1. `$var` is not how you declare a variable in JavaScript. 2. `innerHTML` is dynamic, wait for the JavaScript to put the text there.

Comment: Are you making a firefox addon? Like something that is found on AMO website: http://addons.mozilla.org/ ?